# Does Redactor have a button that adds a horizontal rule (<hr> tag)?

Tags: redactor

Does Redactor have a setting for a button that adds a `<hr>` tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Edit `config/redactor/standard.json` file (or the relevant file in your Craft project) and add `"line"` in the `buttons` items list.

You should see the "Line" button in the toolbar which will add a `hr` tag to your contents.